# MySQL - Count total records sub query?

Tags: mysql

I currently have a query that is like this:

```
SELECT * AS totalCustomers FROM customers LEFT JOIN belongings USING (customer_id) WHERE belonging_id BETWEEN 1 AND 5;
```

I was wondering if I could modify this so that it will return the total number of records in the table customers by modifying it to something like this:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) AS totalCustomers FROM customers LEFT JOIN belongings USING (customer_id) WHERE belonging_id BETWEEN 1 AND 5;
```

I plan to use the total for pagination but would like to make it part of the query so that I don't have to make a second call to the DB to get a total. Is this possible and is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: What's "ON (customer_id)"?

Comment: Oops, that should be USING (customer_id). Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution I was looking for now. I managed to use a subquery to count the total number of customers inside the customers table:

```sql
   SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) FROM customers AS totalUniqueCustomers ) tmp,
      customers c
   LEFT JOIN
      belongings USING (customer_id)
   WHERE
      belonging_id BETWEEN 1 AND 5;
```

Now I have the total unique number of customers from the whole customers table but, also limit the range of records being used for the join afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

For pagination, if you are using `LIMIT`, you can use [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

Answer (score 0):

I think the better and the right way would be to do second query. If you want to get total number of records, then you shoud do subquery to your customers table, but without "where" directive. And if you do so in your main query subquery will be executed as many times as rows returned by your main query.

Answer (score 0):

Using temporary table may do the trick for this case. Although it is a second query it saves from the expensive join operation:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TMP
SELECT *, customer_id as tmp_customer_id 
FROM customers LEFT JOIN belongings USING (customer_id) 
WHERE belonging_id BETWEEN 1 AND 5;
```

You can still get the results from temporary table you create:

```
SELECT * FROM TMP;
```

You will get the number of customers afterwards:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tmp_customer_id) FROM TMP;
```